# Multiple entries for Google Chrome in Open With

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-explorer, file-association

On my computer (Windows 8.1), both the Desktop "Open with" submenu and the corresponding WinRT dialog contain multiple entries for Google Chrome, when invoked for an HTML file.

[image: Windows Desktop Open With dialog displaying three entries for Google Chrome][image: WinRT Open With dialog displaying three entries for Google Chrome]

So far as I'm aware, I only have one copy of Google Chrome installed; certainly only one appears in the Add/Remove programs dialog.

Only one of the entries actually causes the file to open in Google Chrome.

How can I remove the excess entries?